# Selectively updating working directory

Tags: mercurial

I'm working on some code with a partner. Our make files differ slightly courtesy of different build setups. Because of this, so far we have not been tracking this file. However it would be nice to have at least one of ours tracked. The problem is, when that is done and the other person runs `hg update`, their copy gets update and the code won't compile.

Is there a way to track the file, but have it such that you can update the working directory selectively? Or is there some other way I should deal with this problem?

Answer (score 6):

This is a slight variant of the standard "how do I deal with a config file" question. The standard answer in SVN, Mercurial, and Git is: don't track the file, instead track <file>.example. Then each user copies that over to  <file> and tweaks it as needed.

But Makefiles are a bit smarter than config files: they execute code and can include other files. In which case, it starts making sense to track the Makefile normally and have it include another local file if it's present that overrides the default rules. For instance, the following will work with GNU Make:

```
# pull in any local user tweaks
-include Makefile.local
```

Answer (score 1):

MQ extension is the best and The Right Way (tm) to do it (not easiest, but...)

Store common part of file in repo, individual personalisation - in own MQ-patches

Comment: The answer to a basic question like this shouldn't be 'learn the parts of the tool that are so complex, they're not even enabled by default.'

Comment: they are not "so complex", they just not needed to everydoby in everyday life. I grok MQ less than a hour, but it saves me hours of copy-paste work

Comment: Wait, you're telling *me* why MQ isn't on by default?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to combine your Makefiles? Then there is not chance of losing your different configurations by not storing them in version control.

For example, you could add a conditional statement based on the username. My username is ryan and this code echos my name, but if it is run on your computer, it probably will echo "not ryan."

```
all:
    if [ `whoami` = "ryan" ]; then echo "ryan"; else echo "not ryan"; fi
```

Comment: Conditional makefile for **this** situation is bad  style - human-dependent, poorly manageable and scalable - imagine 10-20-50 developers in team

Comment: When they get to that size the can afford to have similar build environments :)